# Loop dependence workaround in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, containers, circular-dependency

I have a protocol that is defined like this:

```
@protocol Container

- (BOOL)putStuff: (Stuff *) theStuff;

@end
```

and class with following declaration:

```
@interface Stuff : NSObject {

}

@property(readwrite,nonatomic,retain) NSObject <Container> * containerHoldingMe;

@end
```

and I get an error on putStuff declaration — "Expected a type". If I change the argument of the method to NSObject, however, it compiles OK — so, I think that Objective C just doesn't allow loop dependence.

In real classes that I'm working at I want to implement two- However, how do I implement such logic without it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the time the compiler evaluates your `Container` protocol, it does not know about your `Stuff` class. You can let the compiler know about your `Stuff` class with a **forward declaration**:

```
@class Stuff;

@protocol Container

- (BOOL)putStuff: (Stuff *) theStuff;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `id` here.

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, retain) id<Container> containerHoldingMe;
```